# How to call a generic method with type constraints when the parameter doesn't have these constraints?

Tags: .net, generics, type-constraints

```
class A { }
interface I { }
void GenericStuff<T>(T x) { }
void SpecificStuff<T>(T x) where T : A, I { }

void Start<T>(T x)
{
    if (x is A && x is I)
        SpecificStuff(x); // <---- Wrong type
    else
        GenericStuff(x);
}
```

I've got the situation illustrated above. In method `Start()` I get a single parameter `x` and depending on it's type I want to call either the `GenericStuff()` or the `SpecificStuff()` method. Naturally, the type constraints prevent me from doing so, and since there are two of them, I cannot get around them by casting.

Is there any way (short of reflection) to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `dynamic`. While this is more or less glorified reflection, it looks much nicer:

```
void Start<T>(T x)
{
    if (x is A && x is I)
        SpecificStuff((dynamic)x);
    else
        GenericStuff(x);
}
```

Please note:
If, at a later point, you change the type constraints of `SpecificStuff` to contain a third interface and you forget to update your `if` accordingly, you will get runtime exceptions and not compile time errors.

Comment: Not bad, I like it! If there's nothing better, I'm accepting this!

Comment: @Vilx-: I don't think there is anything better, because compile time overload resolution doesn't take type parameters into account. And you can't even define a method with the same parameters but different type constraints.

Comment: Well, but the method names are already different. So overload resolution should have no problems with picking the right method, right? I just need to convince it that the parameter is of the right type.

Comment: @Vilx-: Yeah, but because you can't do that - a variable can't have two types - I experimented with overload resolution.